# Is it possible for GPT4All to interpret an image into a text, like chat-gpt-4 does?

Tags: gpt4all, chat-gpt-4

I have this question on GPT4All,
could it be possible for GPT4All to interpret an image (which would be the input)  into a text (as an output), like chat-gpt-4 does?

Thank you for your help.